# How to retrieve user data from two different tables using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to retrieve data of particular user from two different tables such as "Organizations" and "SystemUsers" in which the company details are stored in "Organizations" & his personal info. is stored in "Systemusers" like emailid,password etc..

But what my requirement is I want to retrieve that particular user organization details as well as personal info like emailid, using entityframework in asp.net mvc. Can anyone suggest me the query to do this.

Table: Organizations

public string CompanyName {get; set;}

Table : Systemusers

public string Email {get; set;}

```
 So, I want to retrieve the user company details as well as personal details from two tables so as to display them in search form.Can anyone suggest me query for this????
```

Comment: care to give us the code or tables description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

going by your description and lack of code im assuming that every user will have 0 or 1 organization.

so 1. you will have to make a one to 0 or 1 relation between user and organization then a simple query on the `SystemUser` table will retrieve the Users personal info and because now in this table you will have a foreign key (assuming name to be Organization) you can retrieve the organiation info using `.Organization` property of the retrieved `SystemUser`

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats a great reply. Doing the same in my application now.

Comment: welcome - dont forget to mark as ans or upvote if this helped.